# Printing out binary ASCII code for a character string in C

Tags: c, string, binary, structure, ascii

I need to write a program that reads in a character string and prints out the binary ASCII code for that string. I do not know the length of the string, and I need to implement data structures somewhere in the program. The source code I have written is:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
int dec_to_binary(int c, int d);

//initialize data structure for binary value 
struct binary{
    int value;
};
struct word{
    int w_value;
};

int main(){

char wordd[256];
printf("Input a string of characters (no spaces): \n");
//scanf("%s", w);
fgets(wordd, sizeof(wordd), stdin);
printf("You typed: %s", wordd);
int size_word = sizeof(wordd);

struct word w[size_word]; //stores character string
struct binary b[size_word]; //initizalize corresponding binary array for char string inputted by user

int i = 0;
int char_int = 0;
for (i = 0; i < size_word; i++)
{
    char_int = w[i].w_value;
    b[i].value  = dec_to_binary(char_int, size_word); //stores binary value in binary struct array  
}

printf("The binary ASCII code for this string is: %d", b);

return 0;
}

int dec_to_binary(int c, int d)
{
   int i = 0;
   for(i = d; i >= 0; i--){
       if((c & (1 << i)) != 0){
       return 1;
       }else{
       return 0;
     } 
   }
}
```

When I compile it I don't get any errors, but my output is incorrect:

```
Input a string of characters (no spaces):
eli
You typed: eli
The binary ASCII code for this string is: 2421936
```

I get the returned value 2421936 no matter what input I try. Any ideas as to where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared `b` as a array of struct so if you print the value of `b` it will give you the base address of array.
Use loop to print the array values.
You are using `w` to get the binary value but the input is in `wordd[]` did you copy the value ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to print the values of the individual entries in the array rather than the value of b (which will just print the address of b as b standalone represents the pointer)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized `w`.
Bear in mind that fgets() stores the new-line character within the string, so it's better to remove it, before proceeding. Do something like:

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<size_word; i++) {
    if (wordd[i] == '\0') {
       wordd[i] = 0;
       break;
    }
}
```